# Is the GraalVM catalog down?

Tags: graalvm

Was trying to get R installed via gu command, but got this:

$ gu install R

Downloading: Component catalog from www.graalvm.org

Error: Error downloading component catalog from https://www.graalvm.org/component-catalog/graal-updater-component-catalog.properties: Host is down (connect failed).

Please check your connection and proxy settings. If your machine is behind a proxy, environment variables (http_proxy, https_proxy, ...) must be set appropriately.

--

Is this problem on their side (sounds like it) or something I need to configure?

I was able to install the native-image piece earlier.

Thanks,

Comment: http://downforme.org/is-graalvm.org-down-today-for-everyone

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It was a firewall problem on our side.